# How to mock window.location.search with Jest when testing a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, mocking, window

I'm setting props on a Vue component based on the value of a query string. The code works when I test it manually but I'm struggling to set window.location.search for my unit tests. Here is what I have so far:

```
describe('When query string contains display-alert=true', () => {
    const query = 'display-alert=true';
    window.location = { search: query } 
    
    it('Should set`show-dialogue` to TRUE', () => {
        expect(pageObject.elements.dialogue().props('showDialogue')).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

I tried using something like this but it didn't work: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/11/17/mock-window-location/

As explained, it works when testing manually. The logic in the component is pretty simple:

```
const query = location.search
const displayAlerts = query.indexOf("display-alert=true") !== -1;

const isDialogueVisible = ref(displayOnLoad(query));
```

Answer (score 1):

While the actual solution to this problem involved refactoring the code a little bit to make it easier to test, I was able to update the window.location.search value using the following patter:

```
const searchUrl = `${baseURL + query}`

beforeEach(() => {
    delete window.location
    window.location = new URL(searchUrl)
})

afterEach(() => {
    delete window.location
    window.location = new URL(baseURL)
})
```